# Websphere Out of Memory Issue

Tags: eclipse, websphere, out-of-memory

Tried to update server.xml, deleted dumps and temporary cache files from `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\javasharedresources`

And still not able to start the server.

This is the following error message I get:

`JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv02\bin\javacore.20150210.094417.6468.0009.txt
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I didn't update the server.xml with correct arguments and once I updated server.xml with `genericJvmArguments="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M"` and `InitialHeapSize="1024" maximumHeapSize="2048"`, I was able to start the server.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple causes for the OutOfMemoryError exceptions. It could be that there is a memory leak in one of the applications that is loaded on startup, or the maximum heap size is not set high enough to support all of the components loaded on startup.

It is best to go through a troubleshooting exercise. I suggest you download heap analyzer tool from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c) and analyze the javacore file to see where the potential leak, if any, could be.

If you can't find a memory leak, try increasing the JVM maximum heap size.  Check that your host system has enough RAM to support the chosen maximum JVM heap size.